# OpenText content Web Services metadata

Tags: c#, web-services, opentext, livelink

I have following code:
have 7 different attributes for ReportDetails.
But this code doesn't seem to work, and there is no error.

```
AttributeGroup DocTypeGrp = new AttributeGroup();
DocTypeGrp = docManClient.GetCategoryTemplate(ref otAuthentication, 12456);
StringValue doc = new StringValue();
doc.Values = new string[1];
doc.Values[0] = "Report";
DocTypeGrp.Values[0] = doc;

AttributeGroup rptDetailsGrp = docManClient.GetCategoryTemplate(ref otAuthentication, 45632);
StringValue rptGroup = new StringValue();
rptGroup.Values = new string[1];
rptGroup.Values[0] = string.Empty;
// rptGroup.Values[1] = "2012";
rptDetailsGrp.Values[0] = rptGroup;
rptGroup = new StringValue();
rptGroup.Values = new string[1];
rptGroup.Values[0] = "2012";
rptDetailsGrp.Values[1] = rptGroup;


Node existingNode = docManClient.GetNode(ref otAuthentication, reportFolder.ID); // Set Node
Metadata metadata = new Metadata(); //Create Metadata object
metadata.AttributeGroups = new AttributeGroup[] { DocTypeGrp , rptDetailsGrp };
existingNode.Metadata = metadata; // Set the Metadata objects back onto the node

docManClient.UpdateNode(ref otAuthentication, reportFolder);//Update Node
```

Would really apprecitate any help.

Comment: What do you mean when you say _"It doesn't work?"_. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Trying to add metadata on given folder. but it doesnt add. and there is no error.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are adding the category to `existingNode` object and while updating the node you are passing `reportFolder` which doesn't have the category.

Changing the code as below should resolve your issue

```
docManClient.UpdateNode(ref otAuthentication, existingNode);//Update Node
```